# Single Instance : Launch Mode of Launcher Activity

Tags: android, launchmode

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.jatin.notification">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance" > <!-- Activity A -->
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".NotificationActivity"
            >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".MainActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".DialogActivity"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:noHistory="true"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Dialog.MinWidth" />
        <activity
            android:name=".SecondActivity" /><!-- Activity B -->
    </application>

</manifest>
```

According to Single Instance,the system doesn't launch any other activities into the task holding the instance. The activity is always the single and only member of its task; any activities started by this one open in a separate task.

But, when i navigated from Activity A(Launcher Activity)-> Activity B via startActivity(intent*) instead of being in new Task Activity B gets on top of Activity A's task.
Though when i navigated to A from B via startActivity(intent*) it shows single instance of A.

*NO FLAGS WERE ADDED.

**Why did Activity B pushed on top of Activity A(as Activity had the launch mode : "singleInstance") instead of creating a new task?**

List of activities :

**TaskRecord{14ba4a25 #18 A=com.example.nischay.notification U=0 sz=2}
        Run #1: ActivityRecord{2a37b313 u0 com.example.nischay.notification/.SecondActivity t18}
        Run #0: ActivityRecord{1ab16fa7 u0 com.example.nischay.notification/.MainActivity t18}**

`mResumedActivity: ActivityRecord{2a37b313 u0 com.example.nischay.notification/.SecondActivity t18}
  mLastPausedActivity: ActivityRecord{1ab16fa7 u0 com.example.nischay.notification/.MainActivity t18}`

**Details :**

Device : Lenovo k50a40
 Android Version : 5.0 
CompileSdkVersion : 25

**Code**

`Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class); startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_NOTIFY);`

Comment: post your manifest please

Comment: @DavidWasser Have posted the manifest. Thanks.

Comment: Please try this: install the App on the phone. Now kill the app (go to Settings->Apps->YourApp->Force close). Now launch the app from the HOME screen by clicking on its App-Icon. Now launch `ActivityB`. Now use `adb shell dumpsys activity activities` and check your task(s) in the list. Are there 1 task or 2? Post the relevant information in your question please.

Comment: Thanks. Have followed what you had said and posted the stack trace of activities but both are in same task.

Comment: Hmmm... What device are you testing on? What version of Android on that device? What SDK are you compiling with?

Comment: Also please post the code you use to start `ActivityB` from `ActivityA`.

Comment: Device : Lenovo k50a40
Android Version : 5.0
CompileSdkVersion : 25

Code : 
 `Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
                startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_NOTIFY);`

Comment: please add these details in question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bingo! Finally an explanation for this strange behaviour!

You said you start `SecondActivity` from `MainActivity` like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_NOTIFY);
```

When using `startActivityForResult()`, the `Activity` that is launched **must run in the same task** as the `Activity` that expects the result (ie: the launching `Activity`). Because of that, Android is ignoring the `launchMode` of `MainActivity` and starting `SecondActivity` in the same task.

You have created a conflict that isn't documented. To solve your problem you need to decide what you want. You cannot have a `singleInstance` `Activity` that calls `startActivityForResult()`. Either choose another mechanism to communicate between `SecondActivity` and `MainActivity` or remove the special launch mode for `MainActivity`.

Why do you want `MainActivity` to be `singleInstance` anyway? Is there a reason for this?

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yes, this was the reason. I had thought this but  got confused as according to documentation, 

**For example : if the activity you are launching uses FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK, it will not run in your task and thus you will immediately receive a cancel result.**.

Basically I was creating an editor (MainActivity) accomplishing "singleInstance" .

Comment: I still don't understand why you think you need `singleInstance`. In general you only need that if you are creating a HOME-screen replacement (which you aren't).

Comment: You could accept my answer if it was helpful. This will remove the question from the list of unanswered questions. Or do you still have a problem??

Comment: Yes, it was very helpful. Thanks.
As required, i will update this to a home-screen replacement.